# Zend Framework 2 - Removed form element causes validation to fail

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element

I use a certain form in several places. In one of them I need to ignore a form element which I set programmatically after the validation.

Because it's just an exception I don't want to create a new form. So I thought, I just remove this element in the controller like:

```
$myForm->remove('myElement');
```

The problem is that the form now won't validate. I don't get any errors but the `$myForm->isValid()` just returns an empty value.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using ZF2? I can't find any class inside of Zend\Form component with "remove" and "isValid" methods.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Form.Form.html#remove

Comment: What is the return value of hasValidated before call isValid?

Comment: There is a bug https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4172

Comment: hm, but is there a way to remove the validator as well? doesn't make any sense removing the field and keeping the validator, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27489/discussion-between-maks3w-and-ron)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, finally I [found a solution](https://unofficial-zf2.readthedocs.org/en/wrap/modules/zend.form.quick.start.html)! You can define a `ValidationGroup` which allows you to set the attributes you'd like to validate. The others are not validated:

```
$form->setValidationGroup('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message');
$form->setData($data);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
```

Comment: Great! That's THE solution. I'll use it from now on!

Comment: Congrats ron. I think this is the most acceptable way to go since there is no `detach()` method on `ValidatorChain`.

Comment: Correct answer. Explained by @weierophinney here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/2839#issuecomment-9883750

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I thought about was to remove the validator from your myElement's ValidatorChain. You could get it within the controller with:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get( 'myElement' )->getValidatorChain()
```

It seems like you can't remove from the ValidatorChain, just add. Check this [post](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ValidatorChain-remove-and-edit-validators-td4656571.html). Matthew Weier O'Phinney, from Zend, explains why it can't be done and a possible solution for your scenario.

The way I solve this problem, is checking the 'remove condition' when I create the validator in the FormFilter class. If you use annotations I think it doesn't works for you, so Matthew suggestions is the one you should use.

Or you could try the one in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753359/zf2-form-validation-zfcadmin-and-bjyauthorize-related/15758172#15758172) from @Stoyan Dimov: define two forms, a kind of BasicForm and ExtendedForm. The first one have all the common form elements, the second one is an extended one of the other with the rest of fields. Depending on your condition you could use one or another.

Comment: thanks for this very summed-up answer! unfortunately I'm using `AnnotationForms` and I'd end up with nearly complete redundancy when creating a second form...

Answer (score 1):

In `class ValidatorChain implements Countable, ValidatorInterface`, add a new method:

```
public function remove($name){
    foreach ($this->validators as $key => $element) {
        $validator = $element['instance'];
        if($validator instanceof $name){
            unset($this->validators[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Use like this:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get("xxxxx")->getValidatorChain()->remove('xxxxxx');
```

Comment: ValidatorChain is one of the core classes of ZF2. What about how to add a new method to validationChain instance?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a validator defined for this particular element that you are trying to remove.

In your controller where you are adding new elements to form, there must be addValidator calling like:

> $element->addValidator('alnum');

That is actually causing validation to be failed. So you have removed the element from form but you still have validation defined on that element to be checked.

If you are not able to find this validation adding function in controller, try to see if it has been defined through config file.

You can read further about form validation in zf here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html

Comment: I'm adding the validators via Annotations... any ideas how to remove them in `ZF2`?

Answer (score 0):

I remove the element with:

```
$form->get('product')->remove('version');
```

When I post the form I disable the validator on this element with :

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get('product')->get('version')->setRequired(FALSE);
```