# How to disable/remove a validator of a element depending on the value of another element?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a fieldset that looks like the following:

```
namespace Store\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;    
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class ProductFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('product');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'isSale',
            'type' => 'Checkbox',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Is the product for sale?',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'salePrice',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Sale price',
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'salePrice' => array(
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' =>'NotEmpty',
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                'isEmpty' => 'Enter the sale price.',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Float',
                        'options' => array(
                            'locale'   => 'pt_BR',
                            'messages' => array(
                                'notFloat' => 'Enter a valid price.',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

I need it to work in a way that when the `isSale` is checked the `salePrice` is required, but if `isSale` is not checked `salePrice` is not required. The problem is I don't know how to remove the validator before `isValid()` is called.

I could do it the other way around: remove the validator in the inputfilter specification and add it if `isSale` was checked. But I don't know how to do that neither.

Here is how my form class looks like:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;

class CreateProduct extends Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('createProduct');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Store\Form\ProductFieldset',
            'options' => array(
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'create',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-success',
                'value' => 'Create',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can either do this on Controller-Level and pre-validation check for Values and change the Filters/Validators or you could write your own Validator to achieve this goal.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782107/zend-framework-2-removed-form-element-causes-validation-to-fail/15797261#15797261 (specially the accepted answer).

Comment: @lluisaznar I know that, the problem is my fieldset have a lot of elements, so I would have to whitelist every one of them. But it is not that bad, it could still be used in the `isValid()` method like in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got around the problem by overwriting the `isValid()` method in the form:

```
class CreateProduct extends Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        /* ... */
    }

    public function isValid()
    {
        if (!$this->get('product')->get('isSale')->isChecked()) {
            $this->getInputFilter()->get('product')->remove('salePrice');
            $this->get('product')->get('salePrice')->setValue(null);
        }
        return parent::isValid();
    }
}
```

It feels so hacky though!