# getting "Call to undefined method" error in calling clearValidators.

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to call `clearValidators` in a ZF2 controller after posting a form. But i am getting error.

Call to undefined method Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox::clearValidators()  in UserController.php

```
$element =$form->get('user_tag_id');
element->clearValidators();
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Check validationGroup. You can choose which form elements you want to validate. [check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782107/zend-framework-2-removed-form-element-causes-validation-to-fail/15797261#15797261)

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I have found the alternative.

```
I have remove the filter class and write Custom filter after form Posting. This works


#Filter Striptags
                            $filter = new \Zend\Filter\StripTags();
                            $row =$filter->filter($row);

                            #StringTrim
                            $filter = new \Zend\Filter\StringTrim();
                            $row =$filter->filter($row);

                            #StringTrim
                            $filter = new \Zend\Filter\HtmlEntities();
                            $row =$filter->filter($row);
```